Approximating $\pi$ as a fraction
Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $p(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $n/p(n)$ is the best approximation of $\pi$ (denoted as $\tilde{\pi}_n$). I have two main questions:

Is the sequence $\{p(n)\}$ a known sequence? If so, is there a closed-form expression for it?
Can we establish an upper bound for the absolute error of each approximation, $|\pi - \tilde{\pi}_n|$?

Some observations: From numerical computations for $1 \leq n \leq 2000$, we observe the following:

The results suggest that $\max |\pi - \tilde{\pi}_n|$ decays faster than exponentially. However, I am curious if there is a rigorous way to prove this behaviour. I also like the elegant "arches", so I wonder what can be said about those.
Out of curiosity, this is the error for Euler's number $e$, for $1\leq n\leq 10000$ (the "pillars" seem to have a higher length variance).

In fact, these pillars of irrationality will always occur with some periodicity for any irrational number, never reaching zero. Is this also a definition of an irrational number?

Google "continued fraction". There's a lot of good stuff for you to discover out there.

You can search in the box for approximation \pi (with dollar signs around the \pi) and find many  questions on the subject.

Do your arches have their "pillars" at $n=355$, $n=710$, $n=1065$, $n=1420$, $n=1775$ by any chance? The curves between those are interesting.

This question has been closed because of a duplicate but I would argue that this question touches on different areas than the duplicate. Specifically, the duplicate is about best rational approximations to $\pi$ with denominator is a certain range. This question is about the best approximation for any numerator $n$, and how the errors in these change with $n$. The pattern in these errors alluded to in this question is not covered at all in the duplicate.

@ChrisLewis They do! Related? However these sequences are different after $n=6035$.

This and this might also be related.

Fun fact: $p(n)$ is not just the nearest integer to $\frac{n}{\pi}$. It seems to be the case most of the time, but $n=14$ is a counterexample; the next counterexamples are at $n=344$ and $n=51819$. OEIS doesn't seem to have this sequence. If you look at the fractional part of $\frac{n}{\pi}$ for these $n$ they are very close to $0.5$ (which makes sense).
